# AWS CloudFront still caching when set to "CachingDisabled"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

We are using an S3 bucket to hold customer zip files they created and made ready for them to download.  We are using CloudFront only to handle the SSL.  We have caching disabled.
The customer receives an email to download their zip file, and that works great.  The S3 lifecycle removes the file after 2 weeks.  Now, if they add more photos to their account and re-request their zip file, it overwrites the current zip file with the new version.  So the link is exactly the same.  But when they download, it's the previous zip file, not the new one.

Additionally after the two weeks, the file is removed and they try to download they get an error that basically says they need to login and re-request their photos.  So they generate a zip file but their link still gives them the error message.

I could have the lambda that creates the zip file invalidate the file when it creates it, but I didn't think I needed to invalidate since we aren't caching?

Below is the screenshot of the caching policy I have selected in CloudFront

[image: screenshot of caching policy]